# Access local variable in method?

Tags: python

My script opens one file (a.txt) and copies it to a new file (b.txt).  If the new file exists it indexes the name (b1.txt) so I don't overwrite the existing one.  Now I want to use the latest name for the copied file (b#.txt) outside the function (method? - sorry I'm new to this).

Here's a portion of my script.  I want to use the current value of newFile when i call the replaceAll method to replace some text after I copy the original file.

---

```
class classMain:

    def copyFile(self,origFile,newFile):
        fIn = open(origFile,'r')
        i = 0
        while os.path.exists(newFile):
            i += 1
        newFile = 'b'+str(i)+'.txt'
        fOut = open(newFile,'w')

        for line in fIn:
            fOut.writelines(line)

        fIn.close()
        fOut.close()

    def replaceAll(self,file,searchExp,replaceExp):
        for line in self.fIn(file, inplace=1):
            if searchExp in line:
                line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you wrapping this in a class?

Answer (score 1):

You could: 1) Use a global variable to store the final value of the newFile variable.
2) Return the value of the newFile variable and then pass it as the argument to the replaceAll function

Answer (score 1):

You mention this to be in `class classMain`. While this isn't the best [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) for the problem, you can share the variable `newFile` by writing it back to a member variable like so:

```
class classMain:

    newFile = None
    # ... the rest of your code here.
```

You can then reference the member variable by writing to it and reading from it as `self.newFile` in your class methods. But, as [Kaustubh mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753856/517815), there are other ways to solve this problem. [This documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) may also help you.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't know which file the function is going to create, make it tell you by returning a value:

```
return newFile
```

`return` will immediately end execution of the function it's in, so place it accordingly. In your case, it should be the very last line of `copyFile()`. When you use `copyFile()`, capture the value it returns by assigning it to a variable:

```
savedin = classMain.copyFile(oldname, newname)
```

If you don't care to save the returned value, just call `copyFile` as before, and the returned value is discared.

Some other answers suggested setting a global variable. This may be right in some reasons, but it's a "side effect" since it's not visible in the code that calls your function. Keep it simple and return values until you have a problem that cannot be solved that way.

Comment: Thanks Alexis.  This works well and is clean and simple.  I read your answer first and still need to review the others, at least to understand the options presented and learn from them.

Comment: They give good advice: If your class represents a concept (object) that should know which file it's stored in, it makes sense to record the filename in it. But I think they'll agree that the first tool in your toolbox should be to return a value.